# Notepad++ need help keeping last character in a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a regex that removes everything but numbers, and I need something similar that keeps the last character and removes everything else. I tried searching it on Google but nothing showed up.

Example:

```
user
user
```

to just

```
r
r
```

Comment: have you tried anything? it would be adequate to show your efforts

Comment: I havent found anything on the subject, theres nothing about keeping the last chracther and deleting everything else :(

Comment: What is the expected result if the last character is a space or a punctuation or ...?

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.*([A-Za-z\d])` with `$1` replacement

`.*([A-Za-z\d])` :  `.*` is greedy and match everything 
`([A-Za-z\d])` : capture and match an alphabet or digit

[image]
Result :

```
e
9
e
r
r
```

To capture special characters use `.*(\S)` where `\S` mean any non-space character

Comment: it worked great, but theres some numbers so like for example test becomes just t  and if theres a number it becomes test1 to t1 is there anyway to inclue numbers aswell  so if theres a number its just  like this ,               text1 to 1

Comment: you mean at the end and you want to keep the last digit as well? , if yes then use `.*([A-Za-z\d])`

Comment: No i mean like every line is diffrent, theres maybe one with no numbers at the end of the chracther and one with a number at the end of the chracther, this regex works great but it keep last word and the number

Comment: then simply use `.*([A-Za-z\d])`

Comment: i glad that i could help

Comment: or just `.*(.)`

Comment: @revo try it with a space after the last word , will leave a space and i don't think so op wants a space as replacement but you have a point , let me modify for special characters , thanks

Comment: If spaces are a problem then try `.*(\S)`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
.*(.)
```

... and replace the match with `$1`.